# Mean with differents columns ignoring Null values, Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with different columns, what I am trying to do is the mean of this diff columns ignoring null values. For example:

```
+--------+-------+---------+-------+
| Baller | Power | Vision  | KXD   |
+--------+-------+---------+-------+
| John   |   5   |    null |   10  |
| Bilbo  |   5   |    3    |    2  |
+--------+-------+---------+-------+
```

The **output** have to be:

```
+--------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+
| Baller | Power | Vision  | KXD   | MEAN      |
+--------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+
| John   |   5   |    null |   10  |    7.5    |
| Bilbo  |   5   |    3    |    2  |    3,33   |
+--------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+
```

What I am doing:

```
val a_cols = Array(col("Power"), col("Vision"), col("KXD"))

val avgFunc = a_cols.foldLeft(lit(0)){(x, y) => x+y}/a_cols.length

val avg_calc = df.withColumn("MEAN", avgFunc)
```

But I get the null values:

```
+--------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+
| Baller | Power | Vision  | KXD   | MEAN      |
+--------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+
| John   |   5   |    null |   10  |    null   |
| Bilbo  |   5   |    3    |    2  |    3,33   |
+--------+-------+---------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: what's your spark version?

Comment: Hi! My version is 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode the columns and do a group by + mean, then join back to the original dataframe using the Baller column:

```
val result = df.join(
    df.select(
        col("Baller"), 
        explode(array(col("Power"), col("Vision"), col("KXD")))
    ).groupBy("Baller").agg(mean("col").as("MEAN")), 
    Seq("Baller")
)

result.show
+------+-----+------+---+------------------+
|Baller|Power|Vision|KXD|              MEAN|
+------+-----+------+---+------------------+
|  John|    5|  null| 10|               7.5|
| Bilbo|    5|     3|  2|3.3333333333333335|
+------+-----+------+---+------------------+
```